# How to safely access multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

If I'm trying to access an item in a two dimensional array:

```
const a = b[row][column]
```

if `b[row]` returns `undefined`, this will throw an error.

Is there a short handed syntax to try and access the column safely, besides first checking that `b[row]` is defined with an if statement ?

Comment: `b[row]?.[column]`

Comment: Yes I'm sorry I missed the thread with answers, and thank you very much!